# How the userAgent of Java work in c#

Tags: java, c#

This is the Java Code that is used to open the link by using any browser.

```
    URL url = new URL(s);
    URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();
    spoof.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X                       10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.122 Safari/534.30\"");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));

    String strline = "";
    String finalhtml = "";

    while((strline = in.readLine() ) != null){
        finalhtml = finalhtml + strline;

        System.out.println(finalhtml);
    }
```

How the userAgent work in c# I read few answers but not clearly mentioned there?

Comment: What is your question? From what I'm reading, you're asking how you can use something in C# in Java, and the answer is you can't. They are separate languages.

Comment: I am asking that can you please convert it into c#. I need this because when i simply write  WebClient w = new WebClient();            String s = w.DownloadString("https://yellowpages.com.au/nsw/sydney/allergy-testing-12388031-listing.html?context=businessTypeSearch");
            Console.Write(s);      Nothing is caught in the String. That's why I need useragent type thing(that is in java) need that in c#

Comment: So you're asking us to port code for you? That's not a question. There are plenty of people who will do that for very little money. If you mean you want the C# equivalent, then IceManMind's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Create a new 'HttpWebRequest' object to the mentioned URL.
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=Doctors&locationClue=Sydney%2C+NSW+2000&lat=&lon=");
myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
// Assign the response object of 'HttpWebRequest' to a 'HttpWebResponse'variable.
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        // Display the contents of the page to the console.
Stream streamResponse = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
Char[] readBuff = new Char[256];
int count = streamRead.Read(readBuff, 0, 256);
Console.WriteLine("\nThe contents of HTML Page are :\n");
while (count > 0)
{
String outputData = new String(readBuff, 0, count);
Console.Write(outputData);
count = streamRead.Read(readBuff, 0, 256);
}
// Release the response object resources.
streamRead.Close();
streamResponse.Close();
myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

User agent isn't a C# or Java thing. Its a string that is sent along with a web request that identifies the machine, OS and browser of the originating requester. This is a web standards thing, not a programming thing.

If you are trying to duplicate that Java code into C#, what you are probably looking for is the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes. You can set the user agent of the HttpWebRequest using the [UserAgent property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Your Java code will look like this in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "";
        string s = "http://www.example.com";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(s);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X                       10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.122 Safari/534.30\"";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {               
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
                {
                    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream))
                    {                       
                        data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```